# Algorithm to sort a tag based autocomplete based on frequency of tag use and last used time?

Tags: javascript, sorting, autocomplete, gmail, selectize.js

I am currently building a simple input box which tags the email id entered based on an existing list of names and email Ids. Something similar to what gmail and outlook do when one starts typing an email address into the "To" box.

I have the frequency and lastUsedTimeStamp data against each mail address. Based on this I need to sort the suggestions to bring the most useful option to the top. The first thought I got was to sort based on 'frequency/durationSincelastUsed' but have a feeling that it would dampen the result set heavily. The next thought is to first compare frequencies and then compare timestamps between equally used suggestions.

Does anybody have better ideas? Wonder how Gmail does this. Breaking my head on it for sometime now.

Answer (score 0):

The first time I did something like that, I computed a value based on the time since last used. That value was very high (like 100) if the email address was used in the past 15 minutes. Then it fell off rapidly to 0 after a couple of hours.

My sort used that value first, and then frequency.

The thought behind this is that when you send mail to an infrequently used address, the likelihood of you sending another mail to that same address is high immediately after sending (perhaps you're sending multiple pictures, for example), but then it falls off over a relatively short period of time.

Another method I've used is to maintain a "recent recipients" list of a fixed size. So the last 5 addresses you sent emails to were always shown at the top of the list. Whenever I sent email, I put that address at the top of the list and pushed off the one that was at the bottom.

Both of those are easy to implement, and effective. I found the second to be easier to implement, and I was able to let the user define the size of the recent recipients list.

The second one is also easier to explain to your users. Getting users to understand the sliding time scale in the first one turned out be difficult, and it was nearly impossible to create an interface for them to fine-tune the dropoff period.